# Error in .map() when callback returns a jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/NfzbA/ -- using jQuery 1.9.1

```
var $opts = $('.plant-page').map(function (i, el) {
    return $('<option>');
}).appendTo('#change-page select');
```

The error in the JavaScript console says: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined`

When I switch to jQuery 1.8.3, result is as expected -- the option elements are appended to the select:  http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/NfzbA/2/

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jQuery 1.9.1, if I rewrite the `.map()` callback function to return a DOMelement instead of a jQuery object, it works as expected:  http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/NfzbA/3/

```
var $opts = $('.plant-page').map(function (i, el) {
    return $('<option>').text(this.id)[0];
}).appendTo('#change-page select');
```

When I submitted this as a jQuery bug (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13567), I was told:

> Resolution set to *notabug*
>
> You are trying to append a jQuery object
>   that is inside a jQuery object, since you inserted a jQuery object
>   into said jQuery object via the `$.fn.map()`. This is not supported, but
>   obvious enough. We generally don't make a list of everything that
>   cannot be in a jQuery set because there is an infinite list of
>   possibilities for doing it wrong. Your rewrite looks better.

So: even though this worked in jQuery 1.8, it's considered a reversion to expected behavior rather than a bug. `.map()` callbacks should always return DOMelements instead of jQuery objects.

Comment: I agree with the assessment in the bug report. All jQuery iteration methods work this way. Inside the callback method, `this` is a DOM Node, not a jQuery object, the returned value should be in that same form. `$([$(),$(),$()])` also no longer works even though it used to in the past.

Comment: @KevinB I agree, too -- but then again, `$($some-jQuery-object)` still returns a valid jQuery object!